# Javascript HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, input, bold

I have an input box with an I.D. of "q" on my website...

By entering javascript into the URL bar I can change the place holder text (client side) to say "test"

```
javascript:void(document.getElementById('q').value='test');
```

Now if I wanted to make it say test (but in bold with html) how would I do that??
I tried:

```
javascript:void(document.getElementById('q').value='<b>test');
```

But that won't work.. it's a string! I don't know much javascript...

Thanks all!

Comment: just out of curiosity why are you typing javascript into the address bar if the input is on your site?  If it's because you want to test javascript I would look into firebug for Firefox, or F12 for chrome and IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
document.getElementById('q').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

EDIT:

it should work fine:

```
<a href="javascript:void(document.getElementById('q').style.fontWeight='bold');">bold</a>
<input type="text" id="q" value="some text" />
```

Comment: This didn't work /:   .  .  
javascript:void(document.getElementById('q').style.fontWeight="bold";

Comment: check the syntax, you might be missing brackets etc. i added an example with the complete code in the answer

Comment: Now lets say it is defined:
<input type="text" id="q" ...

How would I change the input type to text/css using javascript?

Comment: what do you mean change the input type to text/css? the form <input> element's type is "text"

Comment: for example I could change the type to "hidden" using URL javascript... I think the bold won't show because the type is just "text"... Is there a setting/type I need to set it to so that HTML things such as <b> can be entered.. or CSS like fontWeight can be entered and visible? I assumed the type would need to be "text/css"

Comment: the form input element - when it is set to text it means that it's a field in which a user can enter. when it's hidden - it means the user will not see it. what you are doing here is changing the "style" of the element. when you have a visible element in the html document (input type=text is a visible element), you can set the style of the element (border, padding, font, font weight, width, height etc). this is what we are doing in this case

Comment: Ahh! Okay, I had to change the class to a blank class that allowed HTML.. working now! Thanks! :)

Comment: So that's how I make it bold! That worked great! What about making the font color red or something (still just using the URL input) ?

Comment: javascript:void(document.getElementById('q').style.color='green');

Answer (score 0):

Just write css for it.

```
#p{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setDefaultText (text) {
                var elem = document.getElementById('q');
                elem.value = text;
                elem.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
            }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            #q {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:setDefaultText('test');">
        <input id="q" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** You can set the font-weight with CSS or JavaScript, but you don't need both.